# how to save textview value in dialog popup?

Tags: android, button, dialog, textview, save

i have 7 textview and 7 buton in dialog popup.
There is one button on the back of dialog popup which increases the count.

my goal is to select any button on the dialog screen and increase the count from the button on the back of the dialog screen and write the texts on the dialog screen.

I can enter the data in the textview next to the button I selected but when I open the x screen again and want to select data for a different button, the data is lost.

this is the button behind dialog screen(main xml)

```
 btn_yellow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(buttonClick);

            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_zikirsec);
            TextView txtclose;
            txtclose =(TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
            final TextView tv_1_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_1_sayi);
            TextView tv_2_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_2_sayi);
            TextView tv_3_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_3_sayi);
            TextView tv_4_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_4_sayi);
            TextView tv_5_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_5_sayi);
            TextView tv_6_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_6_sayi);
            TextView tv_7_sayi=(TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_7_sayi);

           final String sayi1=String.valueOf(count);

            txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv_1_sayi.setText(sayi1);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext1"){

                tv_1_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }
            else if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext2"){
                tv_1_sayi.setText(sayi1);
                tv_2_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }
            else if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext3"){
                tv_3_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }
            else if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext4"){
                tv_4_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }
            else if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext5"){
                tv_5_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }
            else if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext6"){
                tv_6_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }
            else if (tv_secilenzikir.getText().toString()=="mytext"){
                tv_7_sayi.setText(sayi1);

            }

            myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            myDialog.show();

        }
    });
```

this is one of the 7 button in dialog screen

```
public void btn_3_onclk(View view)
{

    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_zikirsec);

    tv_secilenzikir.setText("mytext3");
    myDialog.dismiss();

    TextView txtclose;
    txtclose =(TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
    txtclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a custom dialog , and save the state of these textviews in ArrayList . after that when the dialog want to be dismissed get this arrayList and when ever you want to show in again set this arrayList to dialog.

Here are some code that maybe helpful :

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

                private ArrayList<String> states;


                public CustomDialog(ArrayList<String> states) {
                         this.states = states;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        //Initialize your textViews from arrayList here

                }

                public ArrayList<String> getStates() {
                       return this.states;
                }

        }
```

And the second way is to save these values in sharedPrefs and when you want to instantiate the dialog read from SharedPrefs.